# Can't include d3dx9.h C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

Hi I am fairly new to C++ and I have been trying to get [this](http://www.planet-source-code.com/vb/scripts/ShowCode.asp?txtCodeId=9291&lngWId=3) code to work for the past hour.

I have loaded the project in Visual Studio and converted it to work with Visual Studio 2010. At first, I tried to compile it and I had no success as it told me It could not locate `d3dx9.h`. However, I changed the dependencies & linking and it changed the error. Now it says

`error LNK1181: cannot open input file '..\DXSDK\Lib\d3dx9.lib'`

It's disappointing because I know where the file is:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Lib\x86\d3dx9.lib`

but it is also in the debug folder. Does anyone know why it can't find it? Or maybe there is another reason it can't open it?

Comment: Don't use relative paths unless you know where the linker is running from.  Try an absolute path to start.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up your VC++ directories properly to point to the SDK's headers and libs directories.  There is a good blog post [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsproject/archive/2009/07/07/vc-directories.aspx) on how to configure them.  You'll want to add the appropriate SDK paths to both the Include and Library paths.  IIRC the DirectX SDK makes this a bit easier by providing the `DXSDK_DIR` environment variable which you can reference in VS using `$(DXSDK_DIR)`, so you would add `$(DXSDK_DIR)Include` and `$(DXSDK_DIR)Lib\$(PlatformShortName)` to the Include and Library directories, respectively.